# JVM does not exit when TimeoutException occurs

Tags: java, jvm, executorservice, timeoutexception

I have code which needs to do something like this

There is a list of classes each with some method (lets say execute()). I need to invoke that method on each class and there is a fixed timeOut for each invocation. Now, one of the class's execute method is badly written and results in a timeout due to which the jvm does not exit. I am running the class like this.

```
java ExecutorServiceTest execute TestClass1 TestClass2 TestClass3
```

Why does the jvm not exit after completing the execution of the code?

I get the following output

```
In class 1
In Class 2
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
at ExecutorServiceTest.main(ExecutorServiceTest.java:78)
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
```

The second class's execute times out and after that, the third class's execute also times out. Why does the third class's execute time out?

The jvm does not exit after the execution is complete. What is the reason? Also why is the `TestClass3` execute timedout?

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException;

class Task implements Callable<String> {
    Object instance;
    Method m;
    Object[] input;
    Task(Object instance, Method m, Object[] input) {
        this.instance = instance;
        this.m = m;
        this.input = input;
    }
    public String call() {
        String s = "initial";
        try {
            m.invoke(instance, input);
        }
        catch (RuntimeException e) {
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
        }
        finally {

        }
        return s;
    }
}


public class ExecutorServiceTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String methodName = args[0];
        String className;
        List<Object> instanceList = new ArrayList<Object>();
        for (int i=1;i<args.length;i++) {
            className = args[i];
            Object o = null;
            try {
                o = Class.forName(className).newInstance();
            } catch (InstantiationException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            instanceList.add(o);
        }
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        Iterator<Object> iter = instanceList.iterator();
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            Object o = iter.next();
            Method m = null;
            try {
                m = o.getClass().getDeclaredMethod(methodName, new Class[] {});
            } catch (SecurityException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Task t = new Task(o,m,new Object[]{});
            Future<String> fut = executor.submit(t);
            try {
                fut.get(2,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (TimeoutException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        executor.shutdown();
    }
}


public class TestClass1 {
    public void execute() {
        System.out.println("In class 1");
    }
}


public class TestClass2 {
    public void execute() {
        System.out.println("In class 2");
        boolean b = true;
        while (b) {

        }
    }
}


public class TestClass3 {
    public void execute() {
        System.out.println("In class 3");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ExecutorService.shutdown()` doesn't actually stop any running executors/threads, [it just tells the service to stop accepting new tasks](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdown()):

> `void shutdown()`
>   Initiates an orderly shutdown in which previously submitted tasks are executed, but no new tasks will be accepted. Invocation has no additional effect if already shut down.

Your TestClass2 instance is never going to stop running because it has a `while(true)` loop which is never halted.

If you want to stop the ExecutorService immediately, you can use `awaitTermination(long timeout, TimeUnit unit)` or `shutdownNow()`.

Comment: Both statements do not halt the JVM.

Comment: They're not supposed to. Did you see the part about your TestInstance2 having an infinite loop?

Answer (score 2):

You need to call `executor.shutdown()` or create a daemon thread (using appropriate `ThreadFactory` passed to `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()`

Comment: The executor.shutdown() statement was missing from the code. It does not work even with that statement included.